# Mix native OpenGL and Swing/AWT

Tags: java, c++, swing, opengl

Suppose I have the source code of a charting library which is written in C++ and renders itself by using OpenGL. Now, I'd like to create an AWT/Swing control element that uses this charting and to embed this element into, say, a JPanel. The other elements in the JPanel should be normal JButtons, JSliders, or whatever.

Is it possible to do that? If yes, can you please provide a small code snippet demonstrating how to do that?

Any ideas and hints?

EDIT: Got it! Seems like Java Native AWT does what I want!

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/791/Embed-OpenGL-inside-Java-AWT-Canvas

Comment: Is it a large amount of code? If not it may pay off to port it to Java using JOGL or LWJGL so you don't have to burden yourself with maintaining native code inside Java. But if you must, I guess you could investigate the LWJGL source code to see how it makes OpenGL inside a Swing component possible.

Comment: @Gimby: Thanks, for the advice! Yes, this is a rather large amount of code but nothing one could not port to JOGL. I just wanted to avoid duplacating the code, as the C++ library is used in an Android NDK project already.